# Javascript variable's value not changing

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website and trying to change the value of active car variable which doesn't change even after click on the division the value of activecar remains as .blueimg only even after clicking on the divisions

What is incorrect?

> actions.js file

```
var activecar=".blueimg";
$(".redimg").hide();
$(".greyimg").hide();
$(".silverimg").hide();

$(".red").click(function(){
    hideshow(".redimg",activecar);

});


$(".blue").click(function(){
    hideshow(".blueimg",activecar);

});


$(".grey").click(function(){
    hideshow(".greyimg",activecar);

});


$(".silver").click(function(){
    hideshow(".silverimg",activecar);

});
function hideshow(colour,activecar) {
    console.log("before");
    console.log(activecar);
    $(activecar).hide();
    $(colour).show();
    activecar = colour;
    console.log("After");
    console.log(activecar);

}
```

> This is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>CollegeDunia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="./assets/blue.jpg" class="blueimg"/>
<img src="./assets/red.jpg" class="redimg"/>
<img src="./assets/grey.jpg" class="greyimg"/>
<img src="./assets/silver.jpg" class="silverimg"/>

<div>
    <a class="blue">Blue</a>
</div>
<div >
    <a class="grey"> Grey</a>
</div>
<div >
    <a  class="red">Red</a>
</div>
<div >
    <a class="silver">Silver</a>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="actions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `activecar` inside `hideshow` is not the same as the global variable `activecar` they are not tied to each other. Setting one will not change the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change function's parameter name. It has same name with your global variable.

```
function hideshow(colour, car) { //activecar changed to car
```